# How to print username in content page, from Wordpress CMS?

Tags: wordpress, parameters, pipe

How do I print the logged in username/display name on a content page from a Wordpress CMS editor. E.g. "Hi [Username]" would end up as "Hi John", if they are logged in?

Comment: Do you want the Username, or the user’s first name?  Two different things

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function :

```
<?php wp_get_current_user(); ?>
```

Reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest one - add to your theme's 'functions.php'. If you want to achieve in more professional way, you can create 'shortcodes'.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $username = $user->display_name;

        $content = str_replace('[Username]', $username, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

If you want more details, refer [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user) here.